# Calling a JPanel from Another Class onto the Main Class' JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, japplet

Good afternoon,

As a personal project intended to help me practice using JPanels and subclasses, I am coding a professional web portfolio containing my education, work and volunteer experience, and other notable works using JApplets.

I have the layout set to BorderLayout with the JButtons aligned WEST. When a button is clicked, the JPanels in the CENTER are supposed to switch out with the appropriate panel. However, I am not that far yet.

As of now, I only have a JLabel onto my Home JPanel that says "Home," because I'd like to make sure the method from the Home JPanel class is working before doing anything more. The issue is that the JPanel isn't displaying on the applet.

The thing is, when I move all the code into from the JPanel's class onto the main class, it displays just fine. So I know the problem is with either how I'm constructing the method, or with how I constructed my JPanel's class.

I've tried setting it to visible-- that didn't work. I've tried setting the LayoutManager as a parameter for the class constructor, I've tried adding paintComponent and super.paint(g), I tried using this.home.addHomePanel-- but nothing worked.

I know I'm missing a few things. It would be appreciated if someone could give me a hand. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you for reading.

Main Class:

```
     public class myWebFolio extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
     JButton[ ] menu =
    {
        new JButton("Home"),
        new JButton("Education"),
        new JButton("Work Experience"),
        new JButton("Programming Projects"),
        new JButton("Other")
    };

    //adds panel to memory
    private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    private Home home;


    public void init()
    {
        setLayout (new BorderLayout( ) ); //changes the layout of the appl

        home = new Home();

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        /*
         * Adds an ActionListener to each button
         * and then adds the button to the buttonPanel.
         * Also adds an invisible componenet to give the buttons
         * spacing.
         */
        for (int i=0; i<menu.length; i++)
          {
             menu[i].addActionListener(this);
             buttonPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
             buttonPanel.add(menu[i]);
          }

        add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);   


        home.addHomePanel();


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Home Panel's Class:

```
public class Home extends JPanel
{
    JPanel homePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); 
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Home");

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Home
     */
    public Home()
    {

    }

    public void addHomePanel()
    {
        homePanel.add(label, FlowLayout.LEFT);
        homePanel.setVisible(true);
        add(homePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: *"When a button is clicked, the JPanels in the CENTER are supposed to switch out with the appropriate panel" - See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: In your super class, you never add `home` to anything

Comment: you are not using the terms "subclass" and "superclass" correctly

Comment: By the way, I don't see where `home` is added to the applet?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm sorry if I used any terms incorrectly, I only recently started learning programming. I went over my post and replaced the wrong terms with the (hopefully) correct ones. I apologize for being so slow, but what do you mean when you say that home isn't added to the applet? You likely don't mean private Home home; or home = new Home();, right?

Comment: Do you mean something like adding the entire class: add.home; or add.Home();?

Comment: In other words, the applet's `init()` doesn't call `this.add(home);` as @immibis seems to be expecting.  Meaning `home` wouldn't get displayed.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks for explaining that. I really appreciate your feedback, everyone.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).